# Can Site Workflow be migrated into Power Automate

Tags: power-automate, sharepoint-designer-workflow

Is it possible to migrate Site/Reusable workflows in Power Automate?

Answer (score 1):

Site and Reusable workflows are not available in Power Automate at this point of time.

Please refer the Microsoft guidance documentation for SharePoint designer workflows migration to Power Automate:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/business-apps/power-automate/guidance/migrate-from-classic-workflows-to-power-automate-flows#workflow-types